# How to add +1 to every nth number in list, python

Tags: python

I generated list of zeros.

```
num=raw_input

list=[0]*int(num)
```

I want every 1st and 2nd number after it in list2 to have +1 added to it.

For every 3rd number in list3, I want to have +1 added to it.

I expect the following output.

> list2
>
> 10101010101010
>
> list3
>
> 10010010010010

I have tried to use the following code:

```
list=raw_input 
list=[0]*int(num) 
num2=list(num)/2 
num3=int(num)/3
```

But that one breaks if used on any number except 12, for example:

```
list1 = [1,0]*int(num2) 
list2 = [1,0,0]*int(num3)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: list=raw_input
list=[0]*int(num)
num2=list(num)/2
num3=int(num)/3
But that one breaks if used any number except 12
list1 = [1,0]*int(num2)
list2 = [1,0,0]*int(num3)

Comment: @InzuDesu don't post the code in comments, post it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
for i in xrange(0, len(list)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        list[i] += 1
```

this modifies every second element of list such that 1 is added. You can modify this easily to change every third by changing **i % 2** to **i % 3**.

One quick sidenote: This page is not meant to be used for solving your problems for you. As Abhinav Sarkar asked: what have you tried? Learning programming is not as much about the actual solution as it is about the road to get there.

I see you are new here, however, it is good to get this right from the start. When asking questions - especially when they are as simple as yours - list what **you** tried.

Comment: Btw `xrange(0, len(list))` is stupid, you can just do `for pos, i in enumerate(his_list)`

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is:

```
num=raw_input

list=[0]*int(num)
list2 = []
list3 = []

for x in xrange(len(list)):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        list2.append(list[x] + 1)
    else:
        list2.append(list[x])

for x in xrange(len(list)):
    if x % 3 == 0:
        list3.append(list[x] + 1)
    else:
        list3.append(list[x])
```